# Java formatting for homework

Tags: java

So I am taking an intro Java class and so far I am enjoying it. I have a project for the class that I'm working in that is supposed to use the Java **Diag boxes** to ask for **user input** to create a character for a video game and generate health and currency for the character.

I've got everything finished except when the characters health is generated it is supposed to stop at two decimal places but no matter what I do to tweak my `DecimalFormat` code I can't get it to stop there.

Here is my code:

```
// This imports the GUI
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.*;

// This is the class declaration
public class CharacterGen
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // These are variable declarations
        final double BASE_CURRENCY = 10.55;
        final int BASE_HEALTH = 50;
        int minHealthBonus = 1;
        int maxHealthbonus = 5;

        // This string dictates what is displayed
        // in the input box title, the dialog box,
        // and the type of dialog box
        String charName;
        charName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Enter your character's name", 
            "Welcome to Legendary Epics!",
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        int startingHealth = 50 + (int) (Math.random() * 5);
        double startingCurrency = 10.55 - (double) (Math.random() * 1);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        System.out.printf("%.2s", startingCurrency);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Your name is " + charName
                + " your starting health is " + startingHealth
                + " your starting currency is " + startingCurrency,
            "Your character stats",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

If you guys could take a look, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use DecimalFormat wherever you print out the double value, including the JOptionPane.

Comment: You created `df` but you aren't using it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You just concatenated a double value without formatting it to the string. Try the method `String.format()` as below:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your name is " + charName + " your starting health is " + startingHealth +
" your starting currency is " + String.format("%.2f", startingCurrency),
                                    "Your character stats",
                                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DecimalFormat wherever you print out the double value, including the JOptionPane.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your name is " + charName + " your starting health is " 
           + startingHealth + " your starting currency is " 
           + df.format(startingCurrency),  // add this!
             "Your character stats",
             JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your DecimalFormat isn't used anywhere. You have to use it like

```
df.format(startingCurrency)
```

to get the customized value.